# How to define ESC char in git?

Tags: git, escaping, opensuse

I want to use coloring in git output, e.g.:

```
git log --decorate --color
```

When I issue this command I get output looking like `ESC[1;32m` where `ESC` is in reversed color.
This looks to me as a valid escape sequence, except that the `\033` must be sent and not the characters `E`, `S` and `C`.
When I issue an `ls` command, I get coloring of the files according to the rights.
So nothing wrong with the capabilities.

Is there an environment variable that must be set to the value of the ESC char?
Or am I looking in the wrong direction?
I am running openSUSE 11.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like your terminal (or any program handling the output) did not understand this, and showed `ESC` as a placeholder for the `\033`. If you are using `less` to show the output, then it needs the `-R` parameter.

I'm using the configuration `core.pager=less -XRMSI`, and it works fine here (also an openSUSE, though I'm not sure which version). (Before changing, look up your current configuration with `git config -l`, and remember the old value. Also you may want to read the `less` documentation about the usable switches.)

Comment: Thanks, that did it.
Except it is core.pager and not git.pager!

Comment: This comes from trying to retype instead of simply doing copy-and-paste ... I'll change it, thanks for noting.

Comment: Another option I found useful is: `git config --global core.pager 'less $LESS -FRXS'`

Comment: Nicolas' option is best.  No need for `$LESS`, however, because less will load that automatically.