# How to trigger the handler of a button using an `alt+letter` keybinding?

Tags: r, button, handler, gwidgets

In various programs you can often activate a button using an <kbd>alt+c</kbd> key binding, if for example the button in question is `Close`. How is it possible to do this in `gWidgets2`? Take this example:

```
w <- gwindow("Buttons")
g <- ggroup(cont=w, horizontal=FALSE)

## various buttons

## without icon
b2 <- gbutton("ouvrir", cont=g)

## with a handler
b4 <- gbutton("click me", cont=g, handler=function(h,...) {
    if(svalue(b2) == "open")
        svalue(b2) <- "ouvrir"
    else
        svalue(b2) <- "open"
})
```

How can I have the `c` underlined in `click me`, and the handler of the `b4` button activated when the user activates <kbd>alt+c</kbd>?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711308/how-to-bind-esc-key-to-close-a-gwindow-in-gwidgets